# How to check if a table field is Empty or NULL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a field in my table (Mssql database), "Name (Varchar(20)) NULL)"

How to read the field, which can be Empty or null?

I do like this:

```
if (myReader["Name"] != DBNull.Value || myReader["Name"] !=String.Empty)
```

Is there a built-in c# function to check it ?

(`IsNullOrEmpty()` ?? It doesn't check Database NULL type ?)

Comment: Did you try var fooName = myReader["Name"]; if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fooName)) ?

Comment: That statement will always be `true` because everything will always be unequal to one of your values. Did you mean `if (myReader["Name"] != DBNull.Value && myReader["Name"] !=String.Empty)`?

Answer (score 2):

You must test DBNull.Value obligatory

IsNullOrEmpty test null value C# and empty, but not check null Database like DBNull.Value

Comment: Do DBNull.Value also check the " " ,  space in that database field ?

Comment: DBNull.Value is for test Null database value, if you want test empty or "" (its same) you can use IsNullOrEmpty(myReader["Name"].ToStrin() )